# Write to an HTML file with Python

Tags: python, html, raspberry-pi

I have a couple of graphs I need to display in my browser offline, MPLD3 outputs the html as a string and I need to be able to make an html file containing that string. What I'm doing right now is:

```
tohtml = mpld3.fig_to_html(fig, mpld3_url='/home/pi/webpage/mpld3.js', 
d3_url='/home/pi/webpage/d3.js') 
print(tohtml)
Html_file = open("graph.html","w")
Html_file.write(tohtml)
Html_file.close();
```

tohtml is the variable where the HTML string is stored. I've printed this string to the terminal and then pasted it into an empty HTML file and I get my desired result. However, when I run my code, I get an empty file named graph.html

Comment: Does `print(thtml)` typo occur only in this snippet and not in actual code? Or have you tried built in method `save_html` https://mpld3.github.io/modules/API.html#mpld3.save_html ?

Comment: it was only in this snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you may be reinventing the wheel here. Have you tried something like,

```
mpld3_url='/home/pi/webpage/mpld3.js'
d3_url='/home/pi/webpage/d3.js'
with open('graph.html', 'w') as fileobj:
    mpld3.save_html(fig, fileobj, d3_url=d3_url, mpld3_url=mpld3_url)
```

Note, this is untested just going off of [mpld3.save_html](https://mpld3.github.io/modules/API.html#mpld3.save_html) documentation and using prior knowledge about [Python IO Streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)